# How to use integer from database php

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have

```
| minprice | mediumint(9) | YES |  | NULL |    |
```

I am trying to create a dropdown that will use the interger provided from the database to populate the value in the select statement.

I have tried single, double quotes, no quotes around the numbers and cannot seem to figure out how to use it.

ie.

```
echo $row['maxprice']
// output 350000

<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "350000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>350000</option>

<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= '350000'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>350000</option>

<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= 350000): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>350000</option>
```

The expected value in the select would be 350000

If the output was 340000 I would still expect 350000

If the output was 360000 I would expect 400000

```
<label for="">Max Price</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] < "100000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>-100000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "100000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "150000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>150000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "200000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "250000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>250000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "300000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>300000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "350000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>350000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "400000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>400000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "450000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>450000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "500000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>500000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "550000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>550000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "600000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>600000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "650000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>650000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "700000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>700000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "750000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>750000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "800000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>800000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "850000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>850000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "900000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>900000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] <= "950000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>950000</option>
<option<?php if ($row['maxprice'] >= "1000000"): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>1000000+</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You do realise that code will set More Than One line in the dropdown to `SELECTED`

Comment: Try putting a space between the tag name and the php tag `<option <?php `

Comment: You may also want to add a `value=""` attribute so you know what was selected later when the PHP has to process the forms data

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tired the space did not work, I have another select that is pulling a varchar value and that one works fine, it has something to to with not being able to read the interger from the mysql, I think

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the selected value in the select box is not correct, if that is not clear from my question let me know and I will update it.

Comment: Define "not correct". What do you get instead?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To achieve this , i think You should use The if...elseif...else Statement

see resource :
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

or you can modify your if statement conditions like this

> I know that is coding like that is bad practicing , but that is what he asking for

```
<?php $maxprice = 350000; ?>
<label for="">Max Price</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
<option <?php if ($maxprice < 100000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>-100000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice == 100000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>100000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 150000 && $maxprice > 100000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>150000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 200000 && $maxprice > 150000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>200000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 250000 && $maxprice > 200000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>250000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 300000 && $maxprice > 250000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>300000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 350000 && $maxprice > 300000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>350000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 400000 && $maxprice > 350000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>400000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 450000 && $maxprice > 400000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>450000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 500000 && $maxprice > 450000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>500000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 550000 && $maxprice > 500000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>550000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 600000 && $maxprice > 550000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>600000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 650000 && $maxprice > 600000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>650000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 700000 && $maxprice > 650000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>700000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 750000 && $maxprice > 700000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>750000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 800000 && $maxprice > 750000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>800000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 850000 && $maxprice > 800000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>850000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 900000 && $maxprice > 850000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>900000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 950000 && $maxprice > 900000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>950000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice <= 1000000 && $maxprice > 950000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>1000000</option>
<option <?php if ($maxprice > 1000000) : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>1000000+</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh my. No, do not do this.

Comment: I know that is coding like that is bad practicing , but that is what he asking for

Answer (score 2):

All values received from a database will be a `string` data type. However the PHP lexer, will automatically evaluate numeric string comparisons as an integer or float value.

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E'
>   and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by
>   `PHP_INT_MAX`), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other
>   cases it will be evaluated as a float. [[sic]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

This allows for `"10" > 2` and `"10" > "2"` to be evaluated correctly and without the need of typecasting or using `intval`. [[Example]](https://3v4l.org/9NJmK)

The main reason for your issue is caused by not using a range to limit the min and max prices to select. As a result you will have multiple values set as `selected` and the browser will only show the first as the selected option. To circumvent the multiple selected options issue, you would need to use a conditional range like `$price >= $min && $price <= $max`.

To reduce the repetitive html, you can use an array as your limit definitions, and iterate over the array to draw out the html.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/c6kSq

```php
<?php $limits = [
   '-100000' => [
       'min' => null,
       'max' => 100000
   ],
   '100000' => [
       'min' => 100001,
       'max' => 150000
   ],
    //...
    '350000' => [
       'min' => 300001,
       'max' => 350000
   ],
   '400000' => [
       'min' => 350001,
       'max' => 400000,
   ],
    //...
   '1000000' => [
      'min' => 900001,
      'max' => 1000000,
   ],
   '1000000+' => [
      'min' => 1000001,
      'max' => null,
   ],
]; ?>

<!-- ....... -->

<label for="maxprice">Max Price</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
<?php 
$price = $row['maxprice'];
foreach ($limits as $amount => $limit) { 
    $min = $limit['min'];
    $max = $limit['max'];
    ?>
    <option <?php echo((null === $min || $price >= $min) && (null === $max || $price <= $max) ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $amount; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

---

Alternatively you can also achieve your desired results by using [`range(100000, 1000000, 50000);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to generate your values and use conditions to detect the first `<` and last `>` entries, or `$price >= $amount - 49999 && $price <= $amount` for all other values.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/U9B9m

```php
$amounts = range(100000, 1000000, 50000);
end($amounts);
$last = key($amounts);
//alternatively use $last = count($amounts) - 1;

<label for="maxprice">Max Price</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
<?php foreach ($amounts as $i => $amount) {
    if (0 === $i) { ?>
        <option<?php echo($row['maxprice'] < $amount ? ' selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo '-' . $amount; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
        <option<?php echo($row['maxprice'] >= $amount - 49999 && $row['maxprice'] <= $amount ? ' selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $amount; ?></option>
    <?php if($last === $i) { ?>
        <option<?php echo($row['maxprice'] > $amount ? ' selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $amount . '+'; ?></option>
    <?php }  ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Results

```html
<label for="maxprice">Max Price (20)</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
        <option selected>-100000</option>
           <option>100000</option>
                <option>150000</option>
                <option>200000</option>
                <option>250000</option>
                <option>300000</option>
                <option>350000</option>
                <option>400000</option>
                <option>450000</option>
                <option>500000</option>
                <option>550000</option>
                <option>600000</option>
                <option>650000</option>
                <option>700000</option>
                <option>750000</option>
                <option>800000</option>
                <option>850000</option>
                <option>900000</option>
                <option>950000</option>
                <option>1000000</option>
            <option>1000000+</option>
</select>

<label for="maxprice">Max Price (340000)</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
        <option>-100000</option>
           <option>100000</option>
                <option>150000</option>
                <option>200000</option>
                <option>250000</option>
                <option>300000</option>
                <option selected>350000</option>
                <option>400000</option>
                <option>450000</option>
                <option>500000</option>
                <option>550000</option>
                <option>600000</option>
                <option>650000</option>
                <option>700000</option>
                <option>750000</option>
                <option>800000</option>
                <option>850000</option>
                <option>900000</option>
                <option>950000</option>
                <option>1000000</option>
            <option>1000000+</option>
</select>

<label for="maxprice">Max Price (360000)</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
        <option>-100000</option>
           <option>100000</option>
                <option>150000</option>
                <option>200000</option>
                <option>250000</option>
                <option>300000</option>
                <option>350000</option>
                <option selected>400000</option>
                <option>450000</option>
                <option>500000</option>
                <option>550000</option>
                <option>600000</option>
                <option>650000</option>
                <option>700000</option>
                <option>750000</option>
                <option>800000</option>
                <option>850000</option>
                <option>900000</option>
                <option>950000</option>
                <option>1000000</option>
            <option>1000000+</option>
</select>

<label for="maxprice">Max Price (1000000)</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
        <option>-100000</option>
           <option>100000</option>
                <option>150000</option>
                <option>200000</option>
                <option>250000</option>
                <option>300000</option>
                <option>350000</option>
                <option>400000</option>
                <option>450000</option>
                <option>500000</option>
                <option>550000</option>
                <option>600000</option>
                <option>650000</option>
                <option>700000</option>
                <option>750000</option>
                <option>800000</option>
                <option>850000</option>
                <option>900000</option>
                <option>950000</option>
                <option selected>1000000</option>
            <option>1000000+</option>
</select>

<label for="maxprice">Max Price (1500000)</label>
<select id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
        <option>-100000</option>
           <option>100000</option>
                <option>150000</option>
                <option>200000</option>
                <option>250000</option>
                <option>300000</option>
                <option>350000</option>
                <option>400000</option>
                <option>450000</option>
                <option>500000</option>
                <option>550000</option>
                <option>600000</option>
                <option>650000</option>
                <option>700000</option>
                <option>750000</option>
                <option>800000</option>
                <option>850000</option>
                <option>900000</option>
                <option>950000</option>
                <option>1000000</option>
            <option selected>1000000+</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intval($row['maxprice']) <= 350000
```

Comment: `intval()` is not needed, the PHP lexer will automatically evaluate numeric strings as their integer or float equivalents except when using strict comparison `===` (Example https://3v4l.org/KJO31). See [string.conversion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)